# Execute computational taks in boost asio asynchronous server

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a simple asynchronous server, heavily inspired from the HTTP server example in [boost asio documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) (single-threaded server), which processes requests sent by clients.

My `server` class creates a new `connection` object everytime a new client connects and calls its `start()` method (as in the HTTP server example). A `connection` instance reads the client's request and sends a reply afterwards using asynchronous operations (i.e [`boost::asio::async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) and [`boost::asio::async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html))

Here is a simplified version of the `connection` class :

```
void connection::start() {
    // Read request from a client
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 read_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(
            buffer_data_, REQUET_SIZE);
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, read_buffer,
            boost::bind(&connection::handle_read_request, shared_from_this(),
                    read_buffer, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

// Error handling omitted for the sake of brievty
void connection::handle_read_request(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1& buffer,
    const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
      request req = parse_request(buffer);
      if(req.type_ = REQUEST_TYPE_1) {
          reply rep(...........);
          rep.prepare_buffer(buffer_data_.c_array());
          // Send the request using async_write
          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
               boost::asio::buffer(buffer_data_, rep.required_buffer_size()),
               boost::bind(&connection::stop, shared_from_this()));
      } else if(req.type_ = REQUEST_TYPE_2 {
          // Need to do heavy computational task
      }
}
```

All of this works very well, however, in some cases, I need to perform heavy computational tasks (`REQUEST_TYPE_2`). I can't perform these tasks in my `handle_read_request` because they would block the single-threaded server and prevent other clients from begin served.

Ideally, I would like to submit my heavy computational task to a thread pool and run a method (e.g `connection::handle_done_task(std::string computation_result)`) of my connection class on completion of the task. This `handle_done_task(std::string computation_result)` would send the result of the computation to the client (using `boost::asio::async_write`).

How can do I that ? Are there some issues I should be aware of (Is it safe to call `boost::asio::async_write` on the same socket from mutiple threads) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states explicitly, asio objects (except for `strand`/`io_service`) are not thread-safe, so you shouldn't call `async_write` from multiple threads without synchronization. Instead, use post-to-io_service idiom. Like this:

```
// pseudocode, untested!
if (req.type_ = REQUEST_TYPE_2) 
{
  auto self = shared_from_this(); // lets capture shared_ptr<connection> to ensure its lifespan
  auto handler = [=](computation_result_type res)
  {
    // post the function that accesses asio i/o objects to `io_service` thread
    self->io_->post([] { handle_done_task(res); });
  }

  thread worker([=](const std::function<(computation_result_type res)> &handler) 
  {     
    // do the heavy work...
    // then invoke the handler
    handler(result);
  });
  worker.detach();
}
```